# MVC Web Framework and Mono

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I work in a shop that has a number of very good C# developers who have been using ASP.NET WebForms and would like to move to a MVC framework. To make things more complicated, we would also like to be able to run this under mono.

So my question is, are there any good MVC frameworks for mono, that have been tried and tested in the real world or are we better with Windows Server and IIS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used [Castle Monorail](http://www.castleproject.org/MonoRail/) in Mono 2.0, and haven't had any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can run django with ironpython under mono. I haven't ever tried it but maybe you should check it out.

Sorry if this was unhelpful as you mentioned C# which django is not...

Answer (score 0):

Give a look to http://netfluid.org/ it's a new interesting .net web server and it works on mono